# How to pass variable extracted using json path extractor to another thread group

Tags: jmeter

I am able to extract access_token and pass it to header manager on http request in same thread group .

But I want to use this variable in other tread group also .

I am extracting json value using JSON path extractor:

[Json Path Extractor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZUdP.png)

And Putting it on Header of other Same Thread Group then it work fine :

[Header Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UnlH.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- in 1st Thread Group use [__setProperty() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty) to convert JMeter Variable into a JMeter Property
- in 2nd Thread Group use [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) to access the value

Demo:

[image: JMeter Sharing Variables between thread groups]

More information: [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups)

---

There is a more "intelligent" way of sharing variables between threads/thread groups - [Inter-Thread Communication](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) plugin, check out documentation for comprehensive explanation and test plans examples.